# Rails 4 image url not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, slim-lang

I'm working on a rails project where I need to use an image as a background on a div, but I can't seem to figure out why the full url isn't being generated. It only generates the path **/blog/imageurl.png**. This project uses slim, which isn't something i'm new to.

**My Code**

```
.blog-post style="background-image: url (#{post.image})"
```

**Code that works on the same page to generate the image**

```
= image_tag "#{post.image}"
```

What have I missed to get this working as a background image?

Comment: what is `post.image` field, string or somthing else?

Comment: I beleive it's a string

Comment: just string or specifically procedded like of carrierwave or paperclip?

Comment: seem to just have to prepend asset_path to the value of the `image`.... where had you place the **imageurl.png** in your sources?

Comment: also put `;` to the end pf `.blog-post style="background-image: url (#{post.image})"....

Comment: at first try to access to image directly with **http://yoursite/images/blog/imageurl.png**; if you be able to, when just add lack part of path to string

Comment: It won't show me the image that way. It seems linked to the asset pipeline as it's generating a unique url /image-url-randomstring.png. So I need to access the asset pipeline somehow.

Comment: well try something as follows: `ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("images/" + post.image)` and get access over it

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
.blog-post{style: "background-image: url(#{image_path post.image})"}
```

Comment: I get an error which states    'Expected attribute' on the line which has that code.

Comment: @JamesPardigan i have edited the answer. can you try again.

Comment: @JamesPardigan what does `post.image` returns ? you may need to pass the result to `asset_path`

Comment: post.image returns 'blog/image-url.png'. How would I go about adding the asset_path to this?

Comment: I still get the same error sadly. Really appreciate your help with this.

Comment: @JamesPardigan where is your `blog` directory located ?

Comment: It's within the assets folder, so assets/images/blog/image-url.png

Comment: @JamesPardigan  `.blog-post{style: 'background-image: url("#{image_path post.image}")'}` - give it a try

Comment: @JamesPardigan This certainly works for me. I have an image in `images/blog/1.jpg` path and I am able to add it as background image of my div : `.my-class{style: "background: url(#{image_path 'blog/1.jpg' })"}`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`.blog-post style="background-image: url(#{image_url(post.image)})";`

Comment: Thanks. After playing around, this seemed to get me nearly there. The final code was: .blog-post {style="background-image: url(#{image_url(post.image)})";}

Comment: oh, sorry for forget missing the "url" for css.  i have update the post.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is the string at first be sure that server serves path to images, so enter to broser path like:

> http://yoursite/images/blog/imageurl.png

and make sure that the image is shewn. Next add lack part of path to the string, and add missing `;` char at the at of line:

```
.blog-post style="background-image: url (#{ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("images/" + post.image)});"
```

Comment: This doesn't show me the image, it seems the asset pipeline changes the url, so I need to hook into this.